# Lebesgue-Stieltjes-measure proofing content

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory, lebesgue-measure

I am working on the Lebesgue-Stieltjes-measure:

$\lambda_{F}(]a,b]) = F(b) - F(a)$, where $F: \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ is monotonically increasing.

We have the ring R = {I = $\cup_{i=1}^{n}$ ]$a_{i}, b_{i}$] : $a_{1} < b_{1} < ... < a_{n} < b_{n}, n \in \mathbb{N}$}.

I want to show that $\mu_{F}: R \to [0, +\infty]$ with $\mu_{F}(\cup_{i=1}^{n}]a_{i}, b_{i}]) = \sum_{i=1}^{n}(F(b_{i})-F(a_{i}))$ defines a content.

What I got so far:

Let $A_{1} = \cup_{i=1}^{n}]a_{i}, b_{i}]$ and $A_{2} = \cup_{j=1}^{m}]c_{j}, d_{j}]$. Then we have

$\mu_{F}(A_{1} \cup A_{2}) = \mu_{F}(\cup_{i=1}^{n}]a_{i}, b_{i}] \cup \cup_{j=1}^{m}]c_{j}, d_{j}]$) = *(this is where I'm stuck)*

= $\sum_{i=1}^{n}(F(b_{i})-F(a_{i})) + \sum_{j=1}^{m}(F(d_{j})-F(c_{j})) = \mu_{F}(\cup_{i=1}^{n}]a_{i}, b_{i}]) + \mu_{F}(\cup_{j=1}^{m}]c_{j}, d_{j}]) = \mu_{F}(A_{1}) + \mu_{F}(A_{2})$.

I'm sure it's easy but I just can't see it right now.

Comment: if they are mutually disjoint I think it's clear.  If they are not mutually disjoint then 'disjointify' the collection to make them so